# Expected value of winning the lottery

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, expectation

There are $n$ participants in the lottery and if 1 wins the prize of $M$ USD is divided equally between the participants.

Each participant picks a number from $\{1,\dots,N\}$ randomly (two can pick the same number). The winning number is picked randomly from $\{1,\dots,N\}$.

Admond is one of the participants. Let $A$ be the profit of Admond.

> Given that it doesn't cost money to participate in the lottery. What is the expected value $\mathbb{E}(A)$?

Please help me approach this one.

Comment: Suppose they all manage to pick different numbers.  Can you get the expected value then?  How does the expected value depend on the number of different numbers selected?

Comment: Could you clarify what it means by " if 1 wins, the prize is divided equally between the participants"? Is it the following? **If $1$ is the winning number, then regardless of how many participants have chosen $1$ (and thus "won" the lottery), everybody gets $M/n$ USD. If any of $\{2,\ldots,N\}$ is the winning number, then those $k$ participants who picked that number will share the prize equally, each $M/k$ USD.** Note that in this scenario, the correct strategy for a participant is to pick any number but $1$.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I believe the OP means that there are $n$ participants and if at least one (1) of them wins (with a probability of $1/N$) then the amount $M$ is divided among the winners. It is expected that $n/N$ participants choose the winning number and thus their expected profit is $\frac{M}{n/N}$ the remaining $n-n/M$ participants are expected to earn 0.

Comment: @astudentofmaths Indeed that's a reasonable setting (which I also implicitly adopted). However, why did the OP used the word "participants" at the end of the sentence and not "winners" (like you did)? There are other weird choices of words: (1) using "if" instead of "when". What you described is the rule that always apply, therefore there's no such thing as "if ... else if" (2) Using the number "1" (albeit not inline math $1$) as shorthand for the word "one" is not very common even among those who embrace abbreviations.